# Firebase addListener in onclick method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to attach a firebase database listener in a button's `onClick` method?

I put `datareference.addValueEventListener` in the `onClick` method, but it crashes when I click on the button and try to update a value in firebase.

Do I create a whole new object and use `setvalue` to substitute the old value? In my case, I want to update the points of a user, and here is my onClick method

```
public void itemClick(View view) {
    int position;
    position = (Integer) view.getTag();
    if (taskList.get(position).getWorker()!=null && taskList.get(position).getWorker().compareTo(userEmail)==0) {
        if (taskList.get(position).getStates().compareTo("COMPLETE")==0)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.already_complete), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            taskList.get(position).setStates("COMPLETE");
            db.updateStates(taskList.get(position).getStates(), taskList.get(position).getName());
            Double awardpoint = taskList.get(position).getPoints();
            update(awardpoint);
            search();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.successful_complete), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.fail_complete), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Here is my update method, I didnt put anything here, but it still crashes

```
 private void update ( Double point){
    databaseReference.child("points").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

}
Here is my onCreate method

```
 public void onCreate(){

    currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String curren_uid = currentUser.getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(curren_uid);
}
```

Here is the exception, and it seems that there's a null pointer exception.
I looked a simliar question on stackOverflow, and it says i should "only listenning the bussniness i interest in ".. but my reference is already pointed to the user with specific uid.

```
12-06 20:17:47.401 4399-4399/ca.uottawa.leyaoli.seg2105_final_project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: ca.uottawa.leyaoli.seg2105_final_project, PID: 4399
                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                        at ca.uottawa.leyaoli.seg2105_final_project.Tab2.update(Tab2.java:161)
                                                                                        at ca.uottawa.leyaoli.seg2105_final_project.Tab2.itemClick(Tab2.java:153)
                                                                                        at ca.uottawa.leyaoli.seg2105_final_project.TaskListAdapter.onClick(TaskListAdapter.java:93)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error message or stack trace?

Comment: yes its possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add `addValueEventListener` inside `onClick` method

But to perform update on the firebase database you need to do it outside the `addValueEventListener`

Comment: Your second point is wrong. You can add/update/delete a value inside the listener. All you need is a database reference, like the one used for the listener, and you can do `reference.removeValue()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that `curren_uid` returns `null`. You cannot pass arguments with `null` value into `child()` method. In order to solve this problem you need to review your authentication process.

So to answer your question, yes, it's possible to attach a Firebase listener in a button's onClick method.